# Is it possible to parse latex in YAML note field?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc, papaja

I am using the `papaja` for R and compiling to .pdf. I'd like to include a note field that has latex formatting in it, but it looks like the note field gets parsed so that it doesn't compile latex syntax. Is there a way around this? A short reprex is below.

````
---
title             : "My paper"
shorttitle        : "My jerky paper"
note              : "Forthcoming in \\textit{Journal of Jerkface Psychobabble}."

author: 
  - name          : "A. Jerk"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Back alley, New Jersey"
    email         : "a-jerk@hotmail.com"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "University of Stuff"

authornote: |
  Shout out to my man Wilbur.

abstract: |
  This paper is amazing

keywords          : "Awesome"

bibliography      : ["r-references.bib"]

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no
keep_tex          : yes

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library("papaja")
```


Blah blah blah.


# References
```{r create_r-references}
r_refs(file = "r-references.bib")
```

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}

<div id="refs" custom-style="Bibliography"></div>
\endgroup
````

The resulting .tex file has the following for the note field:

```
\note{Forthcoming in \textbackslash{}textit\{Journal of Jerkface Psychobabble\}.}
```

Is there any way to write the note so that the latex symbols are not parsed this way?

Session info as follows:

```
- Session info -----------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2020-05-05                  

- Packages ---------------------------------------------
 package     * version    date       lib source                      
 assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 cli           2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 crayon        1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 digest        0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 fansi         0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 glue          1.4.0      2020-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 htmltools     0.4.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 knitr         1.28       2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 papaja        0.1.0.9942 2020-05-05 [1] Github (crsh/papaja@b0a224a)
 Rcpp          1.0.4.6    2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 rlang         0.4.5      2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 rmarkdown     2.1        2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 rstudioapi    0.11       2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 withr         2.1.2      2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 xfun          0.12       2020-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)              
 yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.2)
```

Comment: Hey I just looked into this. I wasn't able to recreate the error. It is parsing correctly for me i.e., `\note{Forthcoming in \textit{Journal of Jerkface Psychobabble}.}`, the only edit I made to script was to remove to bib. I am running papaja 0.1.0

Comment: Thanks for checking on this! I added my session info. I'm running the current version, 0.1.0.9942. Do you have a sub-minor version?

Comment: I just updated to version papaja_0.1.0.9942 and now I have the same error as you. I am on OSX. I'll look into this further. I was on 0.1.0.9842 before

Comment: Hi there, I just pushed a commit to the development branch of `papaja` that should make this work as expected (without the need for header-includes). If you like, give it a try and let me know if it works (`remotes::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuring this out in the new version in `papaja` was really hard! My solution is based off [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473220/math-mode-in-document-title-with-r-markdown)

If you remove your note from the title area and instead add it to a `header-includes` part it will work:

```
header-includes:
  - \note{Forthcoming in \textit{Journal of Jerkface Psychobabble}.}
```

In essence, your new yaml need to be:

```
---
title             : "My paper"
shorttitle        : "My jerky paper"

author: 
  - name          : "A. Jerk"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Back alley, New Jersey"
    email         : "a-jerk@hotmail.com"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "University of Stuff"

authornote: |
  Shout out to my man Wilbur.

abstract: |
  This paper is amazing

keywords          : "Awesome"


floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no
keep_tex          : yes

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
header-includes:
  - \note{Forthcoming in \textit{Journal of Jerkface Psychobabble}.}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the most recent development version (`remotes::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")`), you should be able to style the note with the customary markdown syntax:

```yaml
note              : "Forthcoming in *Journal of Jerkface Psychobabble*."
```